# Why does my 'if' statement in my 'why' loop not change one of my objects?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I'm brand new to Java and creating a simple program that takes information output from another program and uses it via command line for a loop. No matter how many times I look at it, I can't figure out why the 'if (minValue > value' doesn't change minValue.

Output given some information that should probably produce a minValue:

```
Count:3
Minimum: 0 @
Maximum: 75 @ DummyDate3 DummyTime3
Average: 45.00
```

Is this a result of the while loop?

```
int minValue = 0;
    int maxValue = 0;
    String minValueTime = "";
    String minValueDate = "";
    String maxValueDate = "";
    String maxValueTime = "";
    int count = 0;
    double average = 0;

    /*
     * For as long as input is going through A date, a time, and a value
     * will come through as a loop If the minimum value is less than the
     * value coming through The minimum value will become the value. If the
     * maximum value is less than the value, the maximum value will become
     * the value.
     */
    while (input.hasNext() == true) {
        String date = (input.next());
        String time = (input.next());
        int value = (input.nextInt());
        if (minValue > value) {
            minValue = value;
            minValueDate = date;
            minValueTime = time;
        }
        if (maxValue < value) {
            maxValue = value;
            maxValueDate = date;
            maxValueTime = time;
        }
        count++;
        average = average + value;
    }

    input.close();

    System.out
            .printf("Count:%d%nMinimum: %d @ %s %s%nMaximum: %d @ %s %s%nAverage: %.2f%n",
                    count, minValue, minValueDate, minValueTime, maxValue,
                    maxValueDate, maxValueTime, average / count);
}
```

EDIT: I have tried Integer.MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE, but both of them result in the values of MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE, respectively.

Comment: `minValue > value` will only evaluate to true if your input has negative integers, since `minValue` is initialized to 0. This is likely not what you want.

Comment: Assign minValue to highest number, maxValue to lowest.

Comment: You'll generally want to initialize Min to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and max to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for this pattern. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30685641/314291)

Comment: It does this with Integer.MIN_VALUE too, though, and results in '-2147482168'. 0 is the only thing that allows maxValue to result in anything other than '2147482168' as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first value assigned to min is 0. If every integer read is bigger than 0, it will never change. What you actually need to do is assing max and min to the minValue and maxValue :

```
int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

This way, the first value read will most likely be lower than the minimum at the moment and the first value will also be higher than the current max value.

The min value can't go higher than this with those values, the max can't go lower than this too.

Comment: This results in:

    Count:3
    Minimum: -2147483648 @
    Maximum: 2147483647 @
    Average: 45.00

Comment: @CralineRashnila you've likely assigned min to MIN and max to MAX. As per shak's answer, you need to switch this around.

Comment: Ohh, now I understand. I apologize, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer using `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` works fine, but another technique used frequently if you know the array or input you are looping through has at least one entry is to initialize `minValue` and `maxValue` to the first entry.

e.g.

```
int firstEntry = input.nextInt();
int minValue = firstEntry;
int maxValue = firstEntry;

while (input.hasNext()) {
    int currentVal = input.nextInt();
    minValue = Math.min(minValue, currentVal);
    maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, currentVal);
}
```

Comment: I didn't propose this solution as she's also assigning a value to the maxDate and maxTime in the case of a change for the maxValue and same thing for the minValue. If she wouldn't care about the dates and times, your solution would be better.

Comment: It's really interesting, I never would have thought of something like this. It's certainly something I'll consider for the future, thank you!