# How can i split a string into integers, symbols and strings, and then store the integer values to use for arithmetic operation

Tags: java

am new here and to java, please i am trying to split a String into integers, symbol and strings. i want to store the integers and use them for an arithmetic operation . i keep getting an error(NumberFormatException) each time i try to convert the split(numbers) string to integers.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static ArrayList<Integer> numbers;
    static String numInt;
    static StringBuffer buffer;

    static void splitString(String str){
        StringBuffer alpha = new StringBuffer(), num = new StringBuffer(), special = new StringBuffer();
        String numS = "";   String nume = "";

        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
                nume = numS + str.charAt(i);
            } else if(Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i))) {
                alpha.append(str.charAt(i));
            } else {
                special.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(alpha);
        System.out.println(special);
        int numInt = Integer.parseInt(nume.trim());

        int numIntr = numInt + 47;
        System.out.println(numIntr);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "thissois8uy293849i0000r";
        splitString(str);`enter code here`
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the digit has two digits, 21 or 3 301 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have to problems, first your number isn't incremented. `nume = numS + str.charAt(i);` needs to be `nume = nume + str.charAt(i);` so it adds numbers to the string.

The second issue is in your example you end up with a value `82938490000` larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`(2,147,483,647) that cannot be stored in an `int`. If you change that to a `long` it will work fine.

```
    long numInt = Long.parseLong(nume.trim());

    long numIntr = numInt + 47;
```

You may want to consider using `BigInteger` which handles even larger values.

```
    BigInteger numInt = new BigInteger(nume.trim());

    BigInteger numIntr = numInt.add(BigInteger.valueOf(47));
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685641/explanation-on-integer-max-value-and-integer-min-value-to-find-min-and-max-value) has more info on max value of integers

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems to be fixed:

1. The following line cannot work as intended:

   ```
   if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
       nume = numS + str.charAt(i);
    }
   ```

   because you overwrite the value of `nume` in every iteration.
2. As the user @DCTID already answered you're using `int` to save the numeric value which is to large. So use `long` instead (or even better `BigInteger`).

Here is the modified code for the `splitString` method in case you are new to Java as you wrote:

```
static void splitString(String str) {
    StringBuffer alpha = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer num = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer special = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            num.append(str.charAt(i));
        } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i))) {
            alpha.append(str.charAt(i));
        } else {
            special.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    long numInt = Long.parseLong(num.toString().trim()) + 47L;

    System.out.println("Number: " + numIntr);
    System.out.println("Characters: " + alpha);
    System.out.println("Special chars: " + special);

}
```